# Does splunk server has any limit on data, when being sent through Curl request with groovy script?

Tags: curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, splunk

It works when Limit is 10.

```
def logContent = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10).join('\n')
```

It throws error when I increase the limit.

```
def logContent = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(1000).join('\n')
```

Using this request format:

```
def curlResult = curl("curl -k ${LOC_SPLUNK_PROD_URL}/services/collector/raw -H \"Authorization: Splunk ${LOC_SPLUNK_PROD_PWD}\" -d '{\"event\": \"${logContent}\", \"sourcetype\": \"manual\"}'  --silent")
```

are there ways to resolve this?

Tried this:

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog.join('\n')
currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog.getLog(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

Comment: command line has a limit. better to put content into a file and then use `--data-binary "@path/to/file` curl parameter instead of `-d`

Comment: Btw, what about the case when log contains doublequote? Your curl command will fail also.

Comment: For now, I am just stuck at the point, where I cannot send the logs. Saving them into the file will not work as the job will run at different nodes and I will not be able to define a fix path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a limit to how much the HTTP Event Collector (HEC) can accept in a single submission.

[As of 9.0.3](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Limitsconf#.5Bhttp_input.5D), it's ~800MB:

```
max_content_length = <integer>
* The maximum length, in bytes, of HTTP request content that is
  accepted by the HTTP Event Collector server.
* Default: 838860800 (~ 800 MB)
```

Comment: I need to send my jenkins job console logs to splunk dashboard using groovy script. But not through post-build script on Jenkins. 
Need to do it by adding script in post action on git for the pipeline.

Comment: @BhavanaYadav - Your question was whether *Splunk* has a limit on how much can be sent at a time. *Splunk*'s limits have nothing to do with the *sending* methodology :)